# Custom Webview Error Screen

Tags: android, webview

I want to create a simple screen, that appears when the webview can't load a page.
I change visibilities of some objects, so the webview is invisible and you can see the screen.

```
webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
                    //visible
                    view.stopLoading();
                    warningText.setText(description);
                    Bar.setVisibility(0);
                    header.setVisibility(0);
                    loadState.setVisibility(0);
                    border.setVisibility(0);
                    aborted.setVisibility(0);
                    warning.setVisibility(0);
                    warningText.setVisibility(0);
                    //invisible
                    Bar.setVisibility(4);
                    webview1.setVisibility(4);

        }
    });
```

But now the problem:
My screen flares, disappears and the Errorscreen of the Webview appears.
Why? And what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In onReceivedError you may finish your webview activity and show some dialog with background below it after that. Also use webview.setVisibility(GONE) on "pageloadstart" and show your progress bar. And webview.setVisibility(VISIBLE) on "pageloadfinish" (sorry, i'm writing from cell phone and don't remember exact names, look at documentation) and hide your progress bar.